# how to ignore a property by attribute in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can i ignore a property by decorating a property with an attribute? the base class `AttributePropertyConvention` doesn't seems to have that ability, or can it? Doesn't find anything sutiable on `IPropertyInstance` to set..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was very easy:

```
public class IgnoreAttributeConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<IgnoreAttribute>
{
    protected override void Apply(IgnoreAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

where IgnoreAttribute is a simple/empty attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I tried creating a convention with either of the two suggestions and even both and none seemed to work with fluent nhibernate 1.3.0.727

```
public class IgnoreAttributeConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<IgnoreAttribute>
{
    protected override void Apply(IgnoreAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.ReadOnly();
    }
}


public class IgnoreAttributeConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<IgnoreAttribute>
{
    protected override void Apply(IgnoreAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Access.None();
    }
}

public class IgnoreAttributeConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<IgnoreAttribute>
{
    protected override void Apply(IgnoreAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Access.None();
        instance.ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

I later found this google groups discussion which although older states you cannot ignore properties with convention, it must be done by overriding the class map if using automapping.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/PDOBNzdJcc4

That is old and I don't know if it is still relevant but that was my experience. I hope this saves someone else the trouble of attempting to use this solution or spurs someone else to point out where I might be going wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to ignore mapping of specific properties on a POCO using Fluent and Automapping only? Finding information on this even now is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The instance.ReadOnly() method tells FNH to not look for changes on the property in the database.  To ignore the property altogether you need to call instance.Access.None().

Answer (score 0):

The following code will prevent a column from generated in your database.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public bool A => true;
}

public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
    {
        if (member.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), true).Length > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return base.ShouldMap(member);
    }
}
```